# Top navigation items in header constantly flickers when typing

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ui-kitten

The image in the header constantly flickers when I type. May I ask how do I stop this flickering at the top right hand corner or accessoryRight? I am using this [TopNavigation component](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/components/top-navigation/overview#topnavigation) from UI Kitten UI library. I don't think this is normal, it shouldn't happen at all. I must be doing something wrongly.

https://youtu.be/fQppQn-RzeE (How do I embed this? Editor, thank you in advance!)

The flickering happens in the title and the right side of the Navigation Header.

I made a separate component for the TopNavigation and then call it in respective screens.

Things I have tried:

- Since the outcome of the Header relies on `navigation props`, I tried using `useState` and `useEffect` (with navProps as the dependency) to save the prop instead of reading directly from `props`, but to no avail
- Directly adding the jsx into the TopNavigation's `accessoryLeft/Right` and `title` options

Any input is welcome, appreciate it!

TopNavigation:

```js
const NavHeader = ({ navProps }) => {
  const navigateBack = () => {
    navProps.navigation.goBack();
  };

  const [type, setType] = React.useState('');

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setType(navProps.type);
  }, [navProps]);

  const BackIcon = props => <Icon {...props} name='arrow-back' />;

  const BackAction = () => (
    <TopNavigationAction icon={BackIcon} onPress={navigateBack} />
  );

  const renderBrand = () => (
    <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
      <Image source={require('../../assets/images/brand.png')} />
    </View>
  );

  const renderLogo = () => (
    <Image source={require('../../assets/images/logo.png')} />
  );

  return (
    <TopNavigation
      style={styles.topNav}
      accessoryLeft={navProps.backNav && BackAction}
      accessoryRight={
        type === 'register' || type === 'profile' ? renderLogo : null
      }
      title={type === 'landing' || type === 'auth' ? renderBrand : null}
      alignment='center'
    />
  );
};
```

Import example:

```js
<KeyboardAvoidingView
      style={styles.kbContainer}
      behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : null}
    >
  <SafeAreaView style={styles.parentContainer}>
    <NavHeader navProps={navProps} /> // Imported custom Header component here
    <ScrollView>
      {other content}
    </ScrollView>
  </SafeAreaView>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps requiring the images just one time and not on every render may help.
Try adding this at the top of the file (not inside a component function)

```
const brandImage = require('../../assets/images/brand.png');
const logoImage = require('../../assets/images/logo.png');
```

And then in your props instead of an inline require use the variables:

```
const renderBrand = () => (
    <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
      <Image source={brandImage} />
    </View>
  );

  const renderLogo = () => (
    <Image source={logoImage} />
  );
```

**Edit**:

Since this didn't work, perhaps utilizing `useMemo` to memoize the components that show the images would work?

Something like

```
const renderBrand = useMemo(() => (
    <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
      <Image source={brandImage} />
    </View>
  ),[]);

  const renderLogo = useMemo(() => (
    <Image source={logoImage} />
  ),[]);
```

Comment: cool Ron! let me try it out. good point! never thought about this. also to highlight, i dont pass the images as props but rather the images reside in the custom header component (i.e. inline imports). then, i call the custom header component in the screen file itself. EDIT: i tried adding the imports at the top of the custom header component, it didn't work. also, declaring in the screen file itself and passing as props didnt work.

Comment: @domster I see. It still seems to me as though a new `Image` is rendered every time and it takes time to load the images, thus the flicker. I suggested another solution in the edit

Comment: you friggin genius! it works! gotta brush up on my hooks. completely forgot about using useMemo. thank you so much Ron!